# Stop GOSMS from encrypting private messages

Tags: sms

I use GOSMS app because it have Private Box Feature which i like the most, but now GOSMS encrypts the messages in private box.

I have to sometimes use the apps which show SMS(of phone) on Computer or in Browser, but private messages are not shown (even not in other apps) because they are being encrypted by GOSMS.

Is there any way that I can temporarily stop the encrypting feature (so SMS can be seen on PC OR BROWSER)?

Also, there are more then 25,000 messages in single conversation so I cant remove that Contact from Private Box because once remove it will start moving sms from private to normal list which will definitely take time, this is an option I am aware of, but don't want to use.